# Vectorized string search in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a challenge that I cannot solve. Have done the mandatory googling and searching, but could not find a proper solution. Might be simple though (that's what I hope for):

I have a Python dataframe (case_content) with following 4 columns.
`case_content = case_content[[‘CASE_NUMBER','CASE_HEADLINE','CASE_DESCRIPTION','wordFound']]`
The last column (`wordFound`) is empty.

Then I have a list of keywords (refered to as StringOne - StringTen):
`wordList =[*'StringOne','StringTwo','StringThree','StringFour','StringFive','StringSix','StringSeven','StringSix','StringSeven','StringEight','StringNine','StringTen'*]`

On my dataFrame I want to search in each CASE_DESCRIPTION field, on each row, to see if one of the keywords from the WordList is present. I use below line to do that:
`case_content.loc[case_content['CASE_DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('|'.join(wordList)), 'wordFound'] = 'match found in description'`

As you can see I assign a standard string '*match found in description*' in the wordFound column if a match is found in the CASE_DESCRIPTION column. This seems to work fine. When doing `print(case_content)` I get a result similar to this:

```
   CASE_NUMBER       CASE_HEADLINE      CASE_DESCRIPTION             wordFound
     345             [title here]     [Description here]     match found in description
     644             [title here]     [Description here]     match found in description
     765             [title here]     [Description here]     match found in description
     803             [title here]     [Description here]     match found in description
```

However, what I actually want to obtain is to add the specific matching word(s) (separated with a comma), in the wordFound column, - like this:

```
CASE_NUMBER          CASE_HEADLINE      CASE_DESCRIPTION             wordFound
     345             [title here]     [Description here]     StringTwo, StringFour, StringSix
     644             [title here]     [Description here]     StringTwo, StringTen
     765             [title here]     [Description here]     StringThree, StringSeven
     803             [title here]     [Description here]     StringFive, StringEight, StringNine
```

Actually I worked out a solution earlier using a nested iterows() approach where I would iterate over the dataframe, and then for each row iterate over each word to see if there is a match within each CASE_DESCRIPTION. Inside of the loop I then added eventual matching keyword(s) in wordFound column (separated with comma). That approach however was more or less useless as my dataFrame is more than 20.000 rows long and the Description field can contain maybe 500 words or more. So with the looping approach it would take like +10 minutes to run over everything.

With the str.contains() approach it seems that I can run through everything in 5-10 secs. which is absolutely acceptable in my use case. I just need to figure out how to add the actual found words instead of the standard sentence as described.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].